# Semantic store and entity hub

Tags: semantics, semantic-web

I am working on a content platform that should provide semantic features such as querying with SPARQL and providing rdf documents for the contained content.

- I would be very thankful for some
  clarification on the following
  questions:
- Did I get that right, that an entity
  hub can connect several semantic
  stores to a single point of access?
  And if not, what is the difference
  between a semantic store and an
  entity hub?
- What frameworks would you use to
  store content documents as well as
  their semantic annotation?

It is important for the solution to be able to later on retrieve the document (html page / docs such as pdf, doc,...) and their annotated version.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Alternative suggestion...*

[Drupal 7](http://drupal.org) has in-built RDFa support for annotation and is more of a general purpose CMS than Semantic MediaWiki

*In more detail...*

I'm not really sure what you mean by entity hub, where are you getting that definition from or what do you mean by it?

Yes one can easily write a system that connects to multiple semantic stores, given the context of your question I assume you are referring to RDF Triple Stores?

Any decent CMS should be assigning documents some form of unique/persistent ID to documents so even if the system you go with does not support semantic annotation natively you could build your own extension for this.  The extension would simply store annotations against the documents ID in whatever storage layer you chose (I'd assume a Triple Store would be appropriate) and then you can build appropriate query and presentation layers for querying and viewing this data as required.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I got the term "entity hub" from the apache stanbol project. 

There are several different CMS instances (some of them different products) involved in this project and my solution needs to handle the contents generated by those instances. 

For me the ideal solution would be a framework that combines a document store with a RDF triple store. If such a thing is not available I would build my document store and connect it to a triple store.

Answer (score 3):

The only `Entityhub` term that I know is belong to [Apache Stanbol](http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/) project. And here is a paragraph from the original documentation explaining what Entityhub does:

> The Entityhub provides two main services. The Entityhub provides the
>   connection to external linked open data sites as well as using indexes
>   of them locally. Its services allow to manage a network of sites to
>   consume entity information and to manage entities locally.

Entityhub documentation:
http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/docs/trunk/entityhub.html

`Enhancer` component of Apache Stanbol provides extracting external entities related with the submitted content using the linked open data sites managed by Entityhub. These enhancements of contents are formed as RDF data. Then, it is also possible to store those content items in Apache Stanbol and run SPARQL queries on top of RDF enhancements. `Contenthub` component of Apache Stanbol also provides faceted search functionality over the submitted content items.

Documentation of Apache Stanbol:
http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/docs/trunk/

Access to running demos:
http://dev.iks-project.eu/

You can also ask your further questions to `stanbol-dev AT incubator.apache.org`.

Answer (score 1):

http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Stanbol](http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement a traditional CMS extended with some Semantic capabilities, or do you want to build a Semantic CMS? It could look the same, but actually both a two completely opposite approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> It is important for the solution to be able to later on retrieve the document (html page / docs such as pdf, doc,...) and their annotated version.

You can integrate Apache Stanbol with a JCR/CMIS compliant CMS like Alfresco. To get custom annotations, I suggest creating your own custom enhancement engine (maven archetype) based on your domain and adding it to the enhancement engine chain.

https://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/components/enhancer/

One this is done, you can use the REST API endpoints provided by Stanbol to retrieve the results in RDF/Turtle format.